# is there a set exists with no interior and no isolated point?

Tags: real-analysis

Is there exists any subset of real number with no interior and no isolated point ?

I know the basic definitions of both of them.I thinks that set of rational number could be one ?

But i m not sure

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\mathbb Q$ is appropriate. It has no interior since $\mathbb R$ \ $\mathbb Q$ is dense, and it has no isolated point since it is dense itself.

$\emptyset$ too.

Comment: To add, I think $\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}$ is also an example?  To generalise, any set $F$ which is dense in $X$, with $X\backslash F$ also dense will have both $F$ and $X\backslash F$ being an appropriate example?

Comment: Yes it is exactly the same argument in that case.